# Need help in importing a CSV file data from Gmail attachment to an existing Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, csv-import

I am new in this group, and I don't have any experience in apps scripts.

I am here asking for some help to develop a script which can import data from CSV file in Gmail attachment. I have to develop a report on daily basis using this imported data from the CSV file. Following are the scenarios.
The CSV files are automatically generated and received to my Gmail inbox on a scheduled time. Those emails can be identified by "sender email id" and "subject". Only one csv file attachment will be there in each mail. The CSV attachments are having same file name but are sent as separate email with separate subjects.
I want to import these csv attachments into an existing Gsheet. Based on mail subject, each csv data should replace the entire contents of the existing sheets of this Gsheet.

I searched web and even in this group for the script but was not successful. I am posting a script which I got from the web. But it's not working.

```
function ExtractCSVFromGmailAndImport() {
 var label = "Report Data"; // Replace with your desired label
 var subjects = ["Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3"]; // Replace with your desired subjects
 var spreadsheetId = "12345678900987654311"; // Replace with your Google Sheets file ID

 // Import CSV data into each sheet
for (var i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) {
 var subject = subjects[i];
 var sheetName = subject;
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);

 // Clear existing data in the sheet
 sheet.clear();

 // Get the Gmail label
 var threads = GmailApp.search('label:' + label + ' subject:' + subject);

 // Retrieve the CSV attachment from the email
 for (var j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
  var thread = threads[j];
  var messages = thread.getMessages();

  for (var k = 0; k < messages.length; k++) {
    var message = messages[k];
    var attachments = message.getAttachmentsByType('application/csv');

    if (attachments.length > 0) {
      var attachment = attachments[0];
      var csvData = Utilities.newBlob(attachment.getDataAsString()).getDataAsString();
      var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(csvData);
      sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

While running this script I am getting error as follows

Error
TypeError: message.getAttachmentsByType is not a function ExtractCSVFromGmailAndImport  @ Code.gs:25

Kindly help me in this script.

Comment: About your error message of `TypeError: message.getAttachmentsByType is not a function ExtractCSVFromGmailAndImport`. Unfortunately, Class GmailMessage has no method of `getAttachmentsByType`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message) Please be careful about this. And, unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't understand your expected result. So, in the current stage, I cannot propose a modified script. I apologize for this.

Comment: I have a google sheet where I could generate daily report. For report generation I need data from 3 files. Those 3 files are generated as csv file and are send to my Gmail inbox. Those 3 csv files are sent as separate 3 emails with respective subjects. Hence each mail contains 1 csv file. These emails are sent to my email on a scheduled time @8 pm. So, I am planning to import these csv files to my google sheet and generate report based on those data. In google sheet there are separate tabs for each csv data. All contents in the tab are replaced with the new csv data. I think you get my point.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Apologies, Tanaike. I sincerely apologize for my poor English proficiency. My desired outcome is to extract the CSV attachments from three separate emails in Gmail and import the data into a Google Sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs since `getAttachmentsByType()` is not a method in Class [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app).

I have tweaked your existing script from using `getAttachmentsByType()` to `getAttachments()` to obtain your desired outcome.

The script works as follows:

1. Clear the existing content of the sheets with the same subject name
2. Search emails with the desired subject
3. If emails exist,obtain the message along with attachments
4. If an attachment is text/csv,paste the content to the sheet with its same subject name

### Modified script:

```
function ExtractCSVFromGmailAndImport() {
  var subjects = ["Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3"]; // Replace with your desired subjects
  var spreadsheetId = "1234545"; // Replace with your Google Sheets file ID

  // Import CSV data into each sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) {
    var subject = subjects[i];
    var sheetName = subject;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);

    // Clear existing data in the sheet
    sheet.clear();

    // Get the Gmail label
    var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:' + subject);

    // Retrieve the CSV attachment from the email
    for (var j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
      var thread = threads[j];
      var messages = thread.getMessages();

      for (var k = 0; k < messages.length; k++) {
        var message = messages[k];
        var attachments = message.getAttachments()[k];
        if (attachments.getContentType() === 'text/csv') {
          var csvData = Utilities.newBlob(attachments.getDataAsString()).getDataAsString();
          var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(csvData);
          sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
        } else {
          Logger.log('No CSV file found.');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample CSV file from email:

[image]

Data 1:

[image]

Data 2:

[image]

Data 3:

[image]

### Output:

[image]

### References:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getattachments

Comment: Please feel free to ask anything related to the answer posted above.

Comment: Mr. George. Thank you deeply for your support. I truly appreciate the effort you invested in resolving my issue.